# How to customize an end time for a YouTube video?

Tags: youtube

I'm trying to figure out how I can specify a custom end time for an embedded YouTube video. I know that I can customize the start time by adding **&start=30**, but I haven't seen anything relating to the end time.

I need to be able to do this for a web app I'm building, so if there is no way provided by YouTube, how might I be able to accomplish this anyway?

I've skimmed over [the documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html) to no avail. Thanks!

Comment: Please mark [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11422551/865175) as the solution.

Answer (score 211):

I just found out that the following works:

> https://www.youtube.com/embed/[video_id]?start=[start_at_second]&end=[end_at_second]

Note: the time must be an integer number of seconds (e.g. 119, not 1m59s).

Comment: Nice. I've been waiting for Youtube to allow this.

Comment: Perfect use case: http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/uMjIvhblxFY&start=52.5&end=80.2&version=3&modestBranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1

Comment: Yeah it _does_ work. Also, `version=3` may not be necessary. Make sure you use the "API" form of the link, like this: `https://www.youtube.com/v/7qkmGjWtG0w?start=840&end=1240&autoplay=1`, not the usual form, which starts like this: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7qkmGjWtG0w`.

Comment: however it seems to return a Flash/SWF stream... Which works fine for me on Chrome/Windows and IE, but not on Firefox.

Comment: Is there a way to load up HTML 5 player with the &end parameter

Comment: This shit changes all the time. Read the API https://developers.google.com/youtube/documentation/

Comment: You can try even using this form: `http://www.youtube.com/embed/BmOpD46eZoA?start=36&end=65` as suggested on this [Ibrahim Ulukaya answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19507833)

Comment: This worked for me: https://www.youtube.com/embed/xSdbFNwWS28?start=118&end=119. Thanks @brasofilo

Comment: Is there a way to do this if you are NOT embedding the video? I just want a regular link that I can share with a start and end time. The video that I want to share does not allow embedding.

Comment: Note that not all videos allow you to embed. For example, https://www.youtube.com/embed/016LXFHpFCk?start=60&end=65 will result in "Video unavailable" whereas https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=016LXFHpFCk&t=60 works.

Comment: The `v` doesn't work for me today but `embed` does. Also, `autoplay=1` is ignored. So this worked: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/x4n1bORDkz0?start=207&end=230`

Answer (score 67):

I tried the method of @mystic11 ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/11422551/506073 ) and got redirected around. [Here is a working example URL](http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/WA8sLsM3McU?start=15&end=20&version=3):

```
http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/WA8sLsM3McU?start=15&end=20&version=3
```

If the `version=3` parameter is omitted, the video starts at the correct place but runs all the way to the end. From the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html) for the `end` parameter I am guessing `version=3` asks for the AS3 player to be used. See:

> end (supported players: AS3, HTML5)

## Additional Experiments

### Autoplay

Autoplay of the clipped video portion works:

http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/WA8sLsM3McU?start=15&end=20&version=3&autoplay=1

### Looping

Adding looping as per the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html) unfortunately starts the second and subsequent iterations at the beginning of the video:
   http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/WA8sLsM3McU?start=15&end=20&version=3&loop=1&playlist=WA8sLsM3McU

To do this properly, you probably need to set `enablejsapi=1` and use the [javascript API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference).

FYI, the above video looped: http://www.infinitelooper.com/?v=WA8sLsM3McU&p=n#/15;19

### Remove Branding and Related Videos

To get rid of the Youtube logo and the list of videos to click on to at the end of playing the video you want to watch, add these (`&modestBranding=1&rel=0`) parameters:

http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/WA8sLsM3McU?start=15&end=20&version=3&autoplay=1&modestBranding=1&rel=0

Remove the uploader info with `showinfo=0`:

http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/WA8sLsM3McU?start=15&end=20&version=3&autoplay=1&modestBranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0

This eliminates the thin strip with video title, up and down thumbs, and info icon at the top of the video. The final version produced is fairly clean and doesn't have the downside of giving your viewers an exit into unproductive clicking around Youtube at the end of watching the video portion that you wanted them to see.

Comment: How to give time in minutes and seconds?

Comment: www.youtube.googleapis.com is giving me a ssl error whilst youtube.googleapis.com is working. However, there seems to be a state problem if you already have seen the video before and left it at a certain point the player ignores the specified start value and jumps right to where you left watching

Comment: Thanks for the http://www.infinitelooper.com/?v=WA8sLsM3McU&p=n#/15;19 - just what i was looking for

Comment: I just tried `https://www.youtube.com/embed/[video_id]?start=[start_at_second]&end=[end_at_second]` and it didn't work. `https://www.youtube.com/embed/[video_id]&start=[start_at_second]&end=[end_at_second]` did. Note the `&start=`.

Comment: @hmj6jmh That is annoying. It means youtube has changed in a way which has shoved `&` characters which are conventionally query delimiters into the path part of the URI.

Answer (score 7):

Use parameters(seconds) i.e. `youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?start=4&end=117`

Live DEMO: 
**https://puvox.software/software/youtube_trimmer.php**

Comment: This is convenient since you can visually select the times instead of calculating the seconds!  While it doesn't seem to work in the example on the bottom, the generated link does work.

Answer (score 4):

Youtube doesn't provide any option for an end time, but there alternative sites that provide this, like
[Tubechop](http://www.tubechop.com). Otherwise try writing a function that either pauses video/skips to next 
when your when your video has played its desired duration.

OR: using the Youtube Javascript player API, you could do something like this:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(evt) {
    if (evt.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
        setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
        done = true;
    }
}
```

[Youtube API blog](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/01/introducing-javascript-player-api-for.html)

Comment: mystic11's answer worked perfectly for me just now.  I wonder whether it's reliable.

Comment: This is wrong `Youtube doesn't provide any option for an end time, but `. Rest is good.

Comment: @NullHead You're looking at something written in 2011. Things change, man.

Answer (score 1):

Today I found, that the old ways are not working very well.

So I used: 
"Customize YouTube Start and End Time - Acetrot.com"
from http://www.youtubestartend.com/

They provide a link into 
https://xxxx.app.goo.gl/yyyyyyyyyy
e.g. https://v637g.app.goo.gl/Cs2SV9NEeoweNGGy9
Link contain forward to format like this
https://www.youtube.com/embed/xyzabc123?start=17&end=21&version=3&autoplay=1

Comment: This is identical to the top voted answer above. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11422551/857012

Comment: Thanks!  I'm assuming (maybe hoping is a better word) this will be a longer-lasting solution than the top voted answer because they can update it when YouTube changes their URL formats (the top-voted answer doesn't work at the moment because of changes to the format).

Answer (score 1):

I was just trying to look up how and found there is a CLIP feature now added by Youtube right under the video that I had never noticed before! [image: clip video link]

Comment: This only allows you to cut one minute.

Answer (score 0):

I use this signature:

```
youtube.com/embed/[YOUR_VIDEO_ID]?start=[TIME_IN_SEC]&end=[TIME_IN_SEC]&autoplay=1
```

https://www.youtube.com/embed/2EWejmkKlxs?start=1230&end=1246&autoplay=1