# Playing YouTube video with start and end time using YouTube API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to figure out how to set a custom start and end time for an embedded YouTube video shown below:

```
https://youtube.googleapis.com/v/BmOpD46eZoA%26start=36%26end=65
```

However the above link is not working properly in the Safari browser. Can anyone suggest how to make this work for the Safari browser?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Your problem is on the encoding of "?"and "&".

```
https://www.youtube.com/v/BmOpD46eZoA?start=36&end=65
```

or

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/BmOpD46eZoA?start=36&end=65
```

simply works fine.

Comment: its playing full video.

Comment: Just edited my answer, the problem you are having is in URL encoding. When it encodes "&" it doesn't work.

Comment: thank you very much. it's working fine in all browsers  both mobile and desktop

Comment: In Safari (os-x), the start is working, but the video just plays to the end, doesn't stop at end-time.

Comment: It's works as a direct link in browser but does not work on Facebook

Comment: It works however, in replay it ignores start and end timings. Any solution for that?

Comment: So no complex time strings with suffixes eh?

Comment: The first link causes a download to happen on Chrome.

Comment: add one more parameter &version=3

Comment: The /v/ link also causes a download to happen on Firefox Android. The embed link works on the desktop site, but not YT app.

Comment: The second one listed works. Perfect for what I needed today.

Comment: not that the embed thing won't work if "Playback on other websites has been disabled by the video owner."

Answer (score 5):

You should try

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/-ZWGpOSS6T0?start=130&end=144&version=3
```

First thing you have to do is of course get the specific time you want your embedded video to start and the specific time you want it to end at. Then convert them into seconds. Let’s say you want to embed only the part of the video starting from 02:16 up to 02:58.

In seconds, your start time would be ( 2 * 60 ) + 16 = 136 and your end time would be ( 2 * 60 ) + 58 = 178.

Next, grab the embed code from the Youtube video, and append the following parameters to the video URL in the embed code:

?start=[your_start_time]&end=[your_end_time]&version=3

Replace [your_start_time] and [your_end_time] with your actual start and end times in seconds so that your embed code would look like this:

Read more here, [How to embed or link to a specific part of a YouTube video](http://www.bloggerseolab.com/2016/01/embed-video-with-timestamp.html)

Comment: not that the embedding thing wont work if "Playback on other websites has been disabled by the video owner."

Answer (score 1):

Try this link, it must be helpful

```
https://www.youtube.com/v/BmOpD46eZoA?start=36&end=65&version=3
```

Comment: Note: version=3 uses Flash API version3. This may not work on iOS which uses html5 player. Remove version=3 to make it work on iOS.