# How to play the youtube videos with start and end times in both desktop and ios devices

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

i am trying to play youtube videos  with start and end times in both desktop and mobiles(must in safari browser ios).
I am getting the youtube url  form database like this.

```
$video_location='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Tvy_Pbe5NA&start=10&end=29';
```

I am using the below code to play the videos.

```
   if (strpos($video_location,'youtube') !== false)
      {
       $parsedurl = parse_url("$video_location");
       $queryvars = explode("&",$parsedurl["query"]);
       $string1 = str_replace("=","/",$queryvars[0]);
       $string2 = $queryvars[1]."&".$queryvars[2];
       $cleanurl = "http://www.youtube.com/".$string1."&".$string2."&".'version=3';
       $videodata = "<embed width=\"100%\" height=\"400px\" src=\"$cleanurl\"
       type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\">
    </embed>";
      }
      else
      { 
       another condition
      }

    above code is working only in desktops with start and end times but in mobile devices start and end times not working properly.thanks!
```

Answer (score 1):

Version makes it Flash player aka AS3, what iOS can play is html5 player.
Get rid of version=3 and look at my answer on [Playing YouTube video with start and end time using YouTube API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507063/playing-youtube-video-with-start-and-end-time-using-youtube-api/19507833#19507833)

As documented here : developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#end End paramater is only supported in AS3 (flash) player, hence won't be available in iOS in HTML5 player.

Comment: i tried this link,
http://www.youtube.com/embed/BmOpD46eZoA?start=36&end=65
but it is not playing with start and end times  in iphone safari browsers

Comment: I just put this in my safari browser in my iOS7 iphone and worked fine. As I mentioned in the other question, your problem is on the encoding of ? and &, not in the link.

Comment: I tried this link,http://www.youtube.com/embed/BmOpD46eZoA?start=36&end=65  in iOS7 iphone, it starts playing from 36 sec, but not stopping at 45 sec, playing full video

Comment: As documented here : https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#end    End paramater is only supported in AS3 (flash) player, hence won't be available in iOS in HTML5 player.

Comment: Thanks, your code is working in iOS7,iOS6 devices, can you suggest me for Windows mobile?