# Trim Youtube videos into part(s) and download that trimmed video to local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-channels

I have a lot of videos in our channels, average length is around 45 minutes. I would like to trim each video to single or multiple short clips (e.g 15 second introduction clips). Youtube allows to cut the video into another new video, so is it possible to just download that trimmed clip without creating a new one on Youtube? Or is there any possible way to do that (e.g APIs, applications,...)?

It would be appreciated to receive any answer.

Comment: Do you have the video files on your server, or somewhere other than youtube, where you can access them?

Comment: No, I don't, the videos were uploaded by other partners. In the worst case, I have to think about downloading the videos but the video size would be very big and costly in term of performance.

Comment: Have a look at this question, which explains how to set the start and end time of a clip in a youtube video via the parameters, which would work well if you are planning to show the clip in an iframe embed for example  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507063/playing-youtube-video-with-start-and-end-time-using-youtube-api

Comment: If you actually need the shortened video file (as opposed to just playing a short clip from a long video on your site) then your best bet would be to download all the videos from youtube and then script the editing using a command line video editing tool, which reads in the start and end times from a csv file or similar.

Comment: Thanks Max, I'd be better going with downloading the videos.

Comment: I have previously used a youtube downloading command line tool called youtube_dl  http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/, however the problem with these sorts of things is that YouTube are constantly updating their code to deliberately make it hard for people to download movies.  This is why there are dozens of chrome, firefox etc plugins to do it - it's a constant battle to keep up (or block, depending on what side you're on).