# Multiple YouTube videos in a single embed URL

Tags: url, youtube, youtube-api, embed

Is it possible to create a single embed URL with multiple videos' start and end times; like below?

`http://www.youtube.com/embed/VTNSdABrKAI?start=134&end=225/embed/I4LoGhyb2uc?start=172&end=257`

So the next clip plays in the same video frame instead of putting multiple embed URLs on a webpage;

http://www.youtube.com/embed/VTNSdABrKAI?start=134&end=225

http://www.youtube.com/embed/I4LoGhyb2uc?start=172&end=257

Or avoid creating, **editing** and uploading a whole new YouTube video and dealing with copyright claims like below?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DNmc618JwE

Comment: Do you mean is it possible to create a custom playlist using the video ID's in the embed URL?

Comment: @NewToJS, Yes, a playlist with the video ID's and a custom start & end time for each video in the playlist.

Answer (score 2):

Youtube allows you to [programmatically create playlists](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/insert) on your channel and [add items to playlists](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert#request-body). 
The `playlistItems/insert` call also lets you [specify](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#resource) a `position`, `startAt` and `endAt` properties for a clip, which seems to cover your use case.

One caveat to using this API - you have to be [registered with them to use it](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert#auth)

A playlist can contain [up to 200 videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs#Playlists)

**UPD**
I ran the following API requests and was able to successfully create [a playlist](https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PL5W0uIHD5lLZAK1reCuTDFpGMPygNDWvm).

```sh
curl --request POST \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet%2Cstatus&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"snippet":{"title":"Sample playlist created via API","description":"This is a sample playlist description."},"status":{"privacyStatus":"unlisted"}}' \
  --compressed
curl --request POST \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"snippet":{"playlistId":"PL5W0uIHD5lLZAK1reCuTDFpGMPygNDWvm","position":0,"resourceId":{"kind":"youtube#video","videoId":"PLOPygVcaVE"}},"contentDetails":{"videoId":"PLOPygVcaVE","startAt":"PT4H37M0.000S","endAt":"PT4H38M0.000S"}}' \
  --compressed
curl --request POST \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"snippet":{"playlistId":"PL5W0uIHD5lLZAK1reCuTDFpGMPygNDWvm","position":1,"resourceId":{"kind":"youtube#video","videoId":"L_LUpnjgPso"}},"contentDetails":{"videoId":"L_LUpnjgPso","startAt":"PT8H37M0.000S","endAt":"PT8H38M0.000S"}}' \
  --compressed
```

But, it appears, Youtube have [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#resource) the `contentDetails.startAt` and `contentDetails.endAt` that I was suggesting you to rely on: start time seems to still work, but the clip plays through to the end.

I would suggest checking out suggestions from [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661905/how-to-customize-an-end-time-for-a-youtube-video) - you might be able to leverage some idea from answers there (like using 3rd parties or Javascript events in the player)

Comment: Could you share an example playlist with 2 videos where the start and end times are specified for both the videos?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the example. `http://www.youtubestartend.com/` cannot add multiple videos. Couldn't find a JavaScript player events' example either.